# How to close connection by channel name (kick user)

Tags: django-channels

At some point of tine a want to close connection by channel name or kick an user? I can't use self.close as I'm not on that user at that point when I want to kick him.
P.S. group_discard does not close a connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can send an event to websocket.diconnect just like the other consumer methods:

```
self.channel_layer.send(
    <channel_name>,
    {
        'type': 'websocket.disconnect',
        'code': <code>,
    }
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think there is no default methods and the process is going to be: 1) Implement closing socket on a frontend by sending a command from channels. (exactly what you posted) 2) Discard a user from a channel_group 3) In receive method (maybe connect as well) add a handler, whenever there is a message from that user, close the socket.